# How to set Emacs variable doc-view-continuous?

Tags: variables, emacs, docview

Can anyone help me set the emacs variable `doc-view-continuous`?

If I set it to `non-nil` then I can use C-n to scroll to the next page.
http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Navigation.html#Navigation

In emacs I have tried:

```
M-x customize-variable
```

followed by `doc-view-` but doc-view-continuous is not an option.

I have also tried:

```
C-x set-variable
```

followed by `doc-view-` with the same problem

Any help will be appreciated.
Alex Olssen

Comment: Note in general that `customize-variable` and `set-variable` only see "user option" variables (which mostly means only variables defined with `defcustom`), so that's another reason (albeit not applicable in this case) why those commands might not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't like customize, add this to your .emacs:

```
(setq doc-view-continuous t)

;; or

(set-variable 'dov-view-continues t)
```

Completion probably doesn't work because doc-view isn't loaded yet.

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
M-x customize-group doc-view RET
```

There you can set `Doc View Continuous`.

See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DocViewMode

Comment: Thanks for your response, sorry my answer is so belated.

I had actually tried this, as I pointed out in the OP. Unfortunately I cannot see the option for Doc View Continuous in that menu. :(

Comment: You wrote that you tried **customize-variable** and I answered that you should use **customize-group**. See the difference? Hint: variable vs. group ;) This works in my version of Emacs (GNU Emacs 23.2.1 on Windows 7)

Comment: Thanks you. Yes this gives me a different menu to previously.